# Logstash Parsing and Calculations with CSV

Tags: csv, parsing, logstash

I am having trouble parsing and calculating performance Navigation Timing data I have in a csv.

I was able to parse the fields but not sure how to approach the calculations (below) properly. Some points to keep in mind:

Data sets are grouped together by the bolded value (it is the ts of when the 21 datapoints were taken
ACMEPage-1486643427973,unloadEventEnd,1486643372422
2.Calculations need to be done with data points within the group
I am assuming some tagging and grouping will need to be done but I don't have a clear vision on how to implement it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

---------------Calculations-----------------

> - Total First byte Time = responseStart - navigationStart
> - Latency = responseStart – fetchStart
> - DNS / Domain Lookup Time = domainLookupEnd - domainLookupStart
> - Server connect Time = connectEnd - connectStart
> - Server Response Time = responseStart - requestStart
> - Page Load time = loadEventStart - navigationStart
> - Transfer/Page Download Time = responseEnd - responseStart
> - DOM Interactive Time = domInteractive - navigationStart
> - DOM Content Load Time = domContentLoadedEventEnd - navigationStart
> - DOM Processing to Interactive =domInteractive - domLoading
> - DOM Interactive to Complete = domComplete - domInteractive
> - Onload = loadEventEnd - loadEventStart

-------Data in CSV-----------

> ACMEPage-1486643427973,unloadEventEnd,1486643372422
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,responseEnd,1486643372533
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,responseStart,1486643372416
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,domInteractive,1486643373030
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,domainLookupEnd,1486643372194
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,unloadEventStart,1486643372422
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,domComplete,1486643373512
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,domContentLoadedEventStart,1486643373030
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,domainLookupStart,1486643372194
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,redirectEnd,0
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,redirectStart,0
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,connectEnd,1486643372194
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,toJSON,{}
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,connectStart,1486643372194
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,loadEventStart,1486643373512
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,navigationStart,1486643372193
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,requestStart,1486643372203
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,secureConnectionStart,0
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,fetchStart,1486643372194
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,domContentLoadedEventEnd,1486643373058
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,domLoading,1486643372433
>   ACMEPage-1486643427973,loadEventEnd,1486643373514

----------Output---------------

```
 "path" =>    "/Users/philipp/Downloads/build2/logDataPoints_com.concur.automation.cge.ui.admin.ADCLookup_1486643340910.csv",
 "@timestamp" => 2017-02-09T12:29:57.763Z,
"navigationTimer" => "connectStart",
 "@version" => "1",
 "host" => "15mbp-09796.local",
 "elapsed_time" => "1486643372194",
 "pid" => "1486643397763",
 "page" => "ADCLookupDataPage",
"message" => "ADCLookupDataPage-1486643397763,connectStart,1486643372194",
 "type" => "csv"
 }
```

--------------logstash.conf----------------

```
input {
file {
type => "csv"
path => "/Users/path/logDataPoints_com.concur.automation.acme.ui.admin.acme_1486643340910.csv"
start_position => beginning
# to read from the beginning of file
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
}
}

filter {
csv {
columns => ["page_id", "navigationTimer", "elapsed_time"]
}

if (["elapsed_time"] == "{}" ) {
drop{}
}
else {
grok {
match => { "page_id" => "%{WORD:page}-%{INT:pid}"
}

remove_field => [ "page_id" ]
}
}

date {
match => [ "pid", "UNIX_MS" ]
target => "@timestamp" 
}
}

output {
elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I the following to get trend my data:

-I found it easier to pivot the data, rather than going down the column, to have the data go along the rows per each "event" or "document"

-Each field needed to be mapped accordingly as an integer or string

- Once the data was in Kibana properly I had problems using the ruby code filter to make simple math calculations so I ended up using the "scripted fields" to make the calculations in Kibana.

  ```
  input {
      file {
         type => "csv"
      path => "/Users/philipp/perf_csv_pivot2.csv"
      start_position => beginning
      # to read from the beginning of file
      sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
  }


  filter {
      csv {
          columns => ["page_id","unloadEventEnd","responseEnd","responseStart","domInteractive","domainLookupEnd","unloadEventStart","domComplete","domContentLoadedEventStart","domainLookupstart","redirectEnd","redirectStart","connectEnd","toJSON","connectStart","loadEventStart","navigationStart","requestStart","secureConnectionStart","fetchStart","domContentLoadedEventEnd","domLoading","loadEventEnd"]
      }
  ```

  grok {
  match => { "page_id" => "%{WORD:page}-%{INT:page_ts}" }
  remove_field => [ "page_id", "message", "path" ]
  }

  ```
  mutate {
      convert => { "unloadEventEnd" => "integer" }
      convert => { "responseEnd" => "integer" }
      convert => { "responseStart" => "integer" }
      convert => { "domInteractive" => "integer" }
      convert => { "domainLookupEnd" => "integer" }
      convert => { "unloadEventStart" => "integer" }
      convert => { "domComplete" => "integer" }
      convert => { "domContentLoadedEventStart" => "integer" }
      convert => { "domainLookupstart" => "integer" }
      convert => { "redirectEnd" => "integer" }
      convert => { "redirectStart" => "integer" }
      convert => { "connectEnd" => "integer" }
      convert => { "toJSON" => "string" }
      convert => { "connectStart" => "integer" }
      convert => { "loadEventStart" => "integer" }
      convert => { "navigationStart" => "integer" }
      convert => { "requestStart" => "integer" }
      convert => { "secureConnectionStart" => "integer" }
      convert => { "fetchStart" => "integer" }
      convert => { "domContentLoadedEventEnd" => "integer" }
      convert => { "domLoading" => "integer" }
      convert => { "loadEventEnd" => "integer" }

    }


     date {
         match => [ "page_ts", "UNIX_MS" ]
          target => "@timestamp"
          remove_field => [ "page_ts", "timestamp", "host", "toJSON" ]
          }
      }
  output {
    elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
  ```

Hope this can help someone else,